# Force Outlook/Exchange to include the email address in FW: headers

Tags: exchange, outlook

In some situations, Fowarding an email using Exchange generates the following style headers in the quoted email

```
-----Original Message-----
From: John James
Sent: 12 February 2013 11:07
To: Albert Hamstel
Subject: Please help
```

The problem here is the emails are missing (in particular the From: email from John James). Is there a way to make Outlook (or Exchange) include the email instead of just the name?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Those aren't the message headers. 2. I don't believe the original sender address will be in the headers of the forwarded message, at least not that I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://superuser.com/questions/151969/including-sender-email-address-when-forwarding-emails-with-outlook-2007

It appears that Outlook formats it based on whether a local contact, autocomplete entry, or GAL entry exists already or not.

I cannot find any ways to modify it to your liking though...it's by design.